# Magento translation error

Tags: localisation

I translated magento to German using FireGento...and The remaining translation done with inline translation. Everything is fine except one message still showing in English. The message is "the requested quantity %s is not available". I want to translate it to " Die gewünschte Menge des Artikels %s ist nicht verfügbar." I tried Inline translation and CSV updation and every possible solutions..but it is the only message doesn't allowed to be translated. Please help me in this regard.

[image]

Comment: check the phtml file and make sure it uses `$this->__()` for translation and that it is not "hardcoded" within the HTML.

Comment: Also, check your js files, it might be hardcoded in there, if it's the case, I'll give you a solution.

Comment: Which Html? Cart? or Inventory? Could you please share a light on this ..it would be very helpful...thanks

Comment: Go to System > Configuration > Developer > Switch scope to view > Debugging > Show template path hint. It'll "square" parts of the design with hints to where they are located.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go into /app/locale/en_US search in order to find the line you want to translate, then if you find it copy it and go into /app/locale/de_DE, do a search in there in order to find the same line in english language and if you find it write beside of it the german translation.

If you don't find the line (in english language) in the /app/locale/de_DE
then go to end of the file copy the sentence in english and write next to it the translation in german.

By the way you have to open the right file in order the translation to be successful. For example i believe you should open the `Mage_checkout.csv` file.

Comment: I have done this also....but didn't get the problem solved..anyway thanks for your effort I appreciate it...

Comment: I have updated 2 csv files Mage_checkout.csv, Mage_CatalogInventory.csv and translate.csv in all the de_DE folder....But still it is not solving this problem..Only this message is not translating....everything else is working fine...